# Need help for environment

Tags: environments

I wrote for a beamer this in my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\definecolor{studentblue}{RGB}{37,34,140}
\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=studentblue}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=studentblue!20!white}
}

\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

to obtain a block with these colours and with "Definition" as title of the block. I want to change the word in the title, I thought it was sufficient to change the word after \BeforeBeginEnvironment and \AfterEndEnvironment between the curly brackets but it isn't. What should I do? Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: of course, my fault.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why, but it seems necessary to explicitly load Italian for `translator` to work.

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usetheme{Dresden}

\uselanguage{Italian}
\languagealias{italian}{Italian}

\definecolor{studentblue}{RGB}{37,34,140}

\BeforeBeginEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white,bg=studentblue}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=studentblue!20!white}%
}
\AfterEndEnvironment{definition}{%
    \setbeamercolor{block title}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=structure.fg!75!black}%
    \setbeamercolor{block body}{parent=normal text,use=block title,bg=block title.bg!10!bg}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{definition}
test
\end{definition}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. However, I don't only need to put the word "Definizione" but a general word, is it possible?

Comment: @FRANCESCO why don’t use directly the `block` environment?

Comment: Because with this environment I can put a structure with blue for the title and light blue for the text, in that case "text", while using block it has no coloured backround